# Multidimensional arrays and pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm reading "The new approach" and met a nice theory.
Whats the difference between `a[0]` and `&a[0]`, in a two dimensional array `a[i][j]`.

It follows like:

```
int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], *p, i;

for(p = a[i]; p < a[i] + NUM_COLS; p++)
 *p = 0;
```

The other thing goes like:

```
int a[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS], (*p)[NUM_COLS], i;

for(p = &a[0]; p < &a[NUM_ROWS]; p++)
 (*p)[i] = 0;
```

Whats the difference between `a[0]` and `&a[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the declaration

```
T a[N][M]; // for any type T
```

the following are true:

```
Expression        Type            Decays to            Value
----------        ----            ---------            -----
         a        T [N][M]        T (*)[M]             Address of a[0]
        &a        T (*)[N][M]     n/a                  Address of a
        *a        T [M]           T *                  Address of a[0][0]
      a[i]        T [M]           T *                  Address of a[i][0]
     &a[i]        T (*)[M]        n/a                  Address of a[i]
     *a[i]        T               n/a                  Value of a[i][0]
   a[i][j]        T               n/a                  Value of a[i][j]
  &a[i][j]        T *             n/a                  Address of a[i][j]
```

`a`, `&a`, `a[0]`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]` all yield the same *value* (the address of an array is the same as the address of the first element of the array), but the *types* of the expressions are different.

So given the above declaration, the expression `a[0]` has type `T [M]` (`M`-element array of `T`), which "decays" to type `T *` unless it's the operand of the `sizeof` operator.  The expression `&a[0]` has type `T (*)[M]` (*pointer* to `M`-element array of `T`).

Assume the declarations

```
T a[N][M];
T *p0 = a[0];
T (*p1)[M] = &a[0];
```

Initially, `p0` and `p1` contain the same value (the address of `a[0][0]`).  However, if we execute the following code:

```
p0++;
p1++;
```

then `p0` will contain the address of `a[0][1]`, while `p1` contains the address of `a[1][0]`.  `p0++` advances `p0` to point to the next object of type `T`, while `p1++` advances `p1` to point to the next object of type `T [M]`.

Comment: NOW I UNDERSTAND ALL OF IT. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`a[0]` is the first row in the 2D array and has type `int [NUM_COLS]`.

`&a[0]` is the address of that row and has type `int (*)[NUM_COLS]`.

In the first code example, `p` is of type `int *`.  Because in certain contexts an array will decay into a pointer to the first element, it is allowable to do `p = a[i]`.  Then `p[n]` and `a[i][n]` are the same.

When the first code segment goes through the `for` loop, it increments `p` by one on each iteration so that it points to a successive element in the row.  So the first code block sets each element in row `i` to 0.

In the second example, `p` is of type `int (*)[NUM_COLS]`, so you can assign the address of a row to it.  As the loop iterates, `p` is incremented so that it points to the next *row*.  So that code block sets each element in column `i` to 0.

Comment: You confuse rows and columns. `a[0]` is the first row, etc

Comment: @Olaf Good catch.  Fixed.

Comment: Not fixed! `a[0]` has type `int[NUM_COLS]`, etc.

Comment: @Olaf Right again.  Addressed `a[0]` and `&a[0]`.

Comment: Ok, that is fixed. Now the "... you can assign an expression of type int [] to it " is still wrong. You have to assign the correct type, which is `int *`. It _just happens_ that `int[]` decays to `int *` in the expression before the assignment. Still effectively you assign an `int *`.

Comment: @Olaf I though what I had written captured that.  In any case, I reworded it to try to make it more clear.

Comment: Let me get this straight.

edit:

for the implementation int *p, its a[i], i assuime this is just passing the pointer to the first element of the row. But. in int (*p)[i], I need to pass the address of the row which is &a[i], right?
So if a[i] is &a[i][0] because &*(a + i + 0), then &a[0] is &*(a + 0), which is a.
a itself aswell is for me the same as a[0], right?

Comment: @FenixxReborn Yes, `a`, `a[0]`, and `a[0][0]` all have the same address, but the *types* of those addresses are different.  So performing pointer arithmetic on each of those addresses yield different results.